# How to get a list of string from `scrapy.follow`

Tags: scrapy

I'm using `scrapy` to crawl some pages and would like to merge information from two webpages.

- Page 1 contains many event titles and urls
- Page 2 contains event information

I used the following code. `list_content` is a list of [GET someURL], not a list of string.

After searching around, it's due to `response.follow` returns a request. So my question is how to get the event information.

```
class TextSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "text"
    
    def parse(self, response):
        list_title = response.css('div.recomedBox_item_min_title p a::text').getall()

        list_urls = response.css('div.recomedBox_item_min_title p  a::attr(href)').getall()
        list_content = [response.follow(next_page, self.extract_info) for next_page in list_urls]

        yield {
            "conference_titles": list_title,
            "conference_content": list_content,
        }

    def extract_info(self, response):
        return ' '.join(response.css('div.txt_body.img p::text').getall())
```

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, `response.follow` returns a scrapy request which is essentially useless unless yielded from one of your parse callbacks. So in order to merge the information from the first page with the contents of the second page, you  need to pass the contents scraped from the first page to the second page's callback and then yield your final result from the second page.

For example:

```py
class TextSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "text"
    
    def parse(self, response):
        list_title = response.css('div.recomedBox_item_min_title p a::text').getall()

        list_urls = response.css('div.recomedBox_item_min_title p  a::attr(href)').getall()
        for url in list_urls:
            response.follow(next_page, callback=self.extract_info, cb_kwargs={"list_title": list_title})


    def extract_info(self, response, list_title=None):
        list_content =  ' '.join(response.css('div.txt_body.img p::text').getall())
        yield {
            "conference_titles": list_title,
            "conference_content": list_content,
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

The output is something like this:
[ title1, title2] ,    content1;
[ title1, title2],     content2;

Is it possible to get something like this:
title1, content1;
title2, content2.

Comment: I add an index in the for loop, and only pass ith element `list_title[i]` to `extract_info`. This works. I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle this. Thanks

Comment: @LeiHao  I don't understand what you are saying.  Please create a [mre] and possibly start a new question